# How does the conjunction "that" affect the meaning of a sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

> 1. She said (that) she was satisfied.
> 2. We are the strongest team (that) Konoha village has to offer.
> 3. Would you like to know why I did that?
> 4. What do you think (that) I am?
> 5. I thought (that) I would help you.
> 6. It's about time (that) you woke up.

Have seen sentences in which the conjunction is being omitted.Why is that?

Comment: It is an indirect speech so *that* should be there. She said ***that***  she was satisfied. If you want to omit it, it should be: She said, *"I'm satisfied"*. If those are *questions*, *that* looks not good to me!

Comment: @MaulikV You can omit *that* in indirect speech. ["Indirect reports of statements consist of a reporting clause and a that-clause. We often omit that, especially in informal situations"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/reported-speech-indirect-speech). For OP : See this article about the [Omission of that](http://www.englishgrammar.org/omission/).

Comment: In #3 you cannot have both *that* (omitted  or not) and *why* . The choice of  one or the other changes the meaning of the sentence. "Would you like to know (that) I did that?" or  "Would you like to know why I did that?"

Comment: It is then *informal* @Laure

Comment: The clause subordinator "that" is omissible (i.e. optional) in your examples 1-2 and 4-6 where the choice is a matter of formality, the 'bare' clause being slightly more informal. However, in 3. "that" is not permitted at all and must be omitted.

Comment: Thanks BillJ, I edited 3. Which bare clause you are talking about?

Comment: 3. is fine now. If you're interested, "why" is an interrogative clause subordinator introducing the subordinate interrogative clause "why I did that?". The meaning is "Would you like to know the answer to the question 'Why did I do that?"';

Comment: When I said 'bare', I meant the clauses without "that". Omitting "that" is fine, just a little informal, that's all.

Comment: @BillJ Please make your comment an answer so I may upvote it.